# Whats the right approach to send TEXT telemetry to Azure IOTCENTRAL?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

I'm trying to make a car parking type of application and I need to send the following data to IOTCENTRE
Checkin-Time:timestampl
CheckOut-Time:timestamp
Car-Registration-Number:TEXT/alphanumeric

The first two can be simply send via sendEvent as telemetry and iotCentral will plot them on a graph for me. However, I can't find a way to send the alphanumeric data/number plate. The approach I have in mind is updating the device twin properties by adding a "RegistrationNumber" property in my device templates on iotCentral but that approach just feels stupid. Is there a better way to do it?

PS The whole reason I am doing this with IOTCentral to save myself from creating a front-end for the application(which iotCentral provides already). I know you could send text telemetry and even forward it to a storage account blob/structurd. What would be the right approach to do the same with iotCentral(and having the data stored in blob/DB to retrieve later for CRUD operations.

Comment: try the following: put the *plate* property to the telemetry data and map it to the *Measurements.Event* with a Severity=Information in the IoT Central app.

Comment: What is the "device" in your solution?  Each user or vehicle?